# Accessing DOM element in async AJAX callback returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I run a function named `hookUser` to query a DB every 2 seconds to check if a user is online, but it raises this error:

> `cannot read innerHTML of undefined`

I suspect it's because the async callback is not in same scope?

The issue is that I can't pass the button object into that callback, can I do it? If not, is there another way to make this work?

Any help is appreciated.

```
            <script>
                function hookUser(user)
                {
                    console.log('HOOKED USER: '+user);
                     setInterval(
                         function(user)
                         {
                            var ajaxurl = 'checkonline.php',
                            data =  {'username':user};
                            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                                var button = document.getElementById('button_'+user);
                                if(response){
                                    console.log(user+'ONLINE');
                                    //button.innerHTML = 'ONLINE';
                                    //button.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-success';
                                }else{
                                    console.log(user+'ONLINE');
                                    //button.innerHTML = 'OFFLINE';
                                    //button.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-danger';
                                }
                            });
                         },2000);
                }
                </script>
...
<div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="col-md-12 thumb-user " >
                            <div>
                            <button id='button_<?php echo $current_user;?>' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' >Unknown</button>
                            <?php echo '<script>hookUser(\''.$current_user.'\');</script>';?>
...
```

Comment: Pass a reference to the button as a parameter of your function.

Comment: how can you do that though, don't the ajax callbacks have fixed parameters? Ie just the response.

Comment: In hookUser(user, *add this ->* btn) where you pass the user it's calling, and the button it will be affecting.

Comment: Looks like you're already accessing the button, but you just have it inside the ajax call. Just move it *above* the `$.ajax()` line

Answer (score -4, accepted):

My issue was that I was trying to add a parameter to a function that couldn't take one, so the parameter was undefined for user, hence the button based on user ID was undefined.

NB: to anyone trying to copy this code, do not, the hosting site will think you're DDOSing them, instead get user's items at once from DB, then load it into an array.

```
 console.log('HOOKED USER: '+user);
                     setInterval(
                         function()
                         {
                            var ajaxurl = 'checkonline.php',
                            data =  {'username':user};
                             var button = document.getElementById('button_'+user);
                            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                                if(response){
                                    console.log(user+'ONLINE');
                                    button.innerHTML = 'ONLINE';
                                    button.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-success';
                                }else{
                                    console.log(user+'ONLINE');
                                    button.innerHTML = 'OFFLINE';
                                    button.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-danger';
                                }
                            });
                         },2000);
                }
```

Comment: The code you have listed above is *exactly* what we recommended after you clarified your position. Spare us your theatrics, please. Keep in mind, per SO's rules, you haven't provided minimal usable code to even be able to *test* the problem you're having. The issues you're having are your own design, by not properly providing a codebase. Food for thought.

Comment: no, the issue wasn't having button declared before the ajax, it was about having user as a param in _setInterval_ , so yes, you all were wrong, and that was visible in the example, but yes I apologize for "the theatrics"

Comment: You realize we are on here for free, right? Nobody is getting paid to help you, and part of the 'theatrics' is the entitlement and judgement when someone's help doesn't magically fix your problem. I'm sorry we weren't able to adequately help you, but at least we're trying to help. I'd encourage you to read the rules about maintaining a respectful tone. Glad you got it sorted. Have a great day.

Comment: I'm not entitled, I was just surprised that for once you very helpful, smart and knowledgeable people (I'm not being sarcastic) didn't see that very obvious flaw in that short code snippet, like, I'm not surprised I missed it cos A) I'm not as smart as you guys, B) js isn't my best language, cmon though bro, I know I was out of line but no  need to get so offended at being called "woefully wrong", Jesus loves you and so do I

Comment: It's nothing to do with being offended, and everything to do with upholding the respectful nature of this site. I'm not offended at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it before the callback

```
...    
var button = document.getElementById('button_'+user);
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    console.log(button);
    ...
```